# Can't fetch from same repository in Bitbucket Pipelines

Tags: bash, ssh, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to do the following with Bitbucket Pipelines when i push to my test brand:

```
- git fetch
- git checkout master
- git pull origin test
- git push origin master
```

But i get the following message on git fetch: Permission denied (publickey). I was following this tutorial https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html so i already added an ssh key, but cannot understand what are the next steps that i need for the execution to have permissions to connect to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

If “from same repository” really means that you want to access the repository in which the pipeline runs, the answer is: you don’t need that. When the pipeline runs, it starts the Docker image you defined in your YAML configuration and *automatically* checks out the commit you pushed. This means that at the moment when when your command (`git fetch`) is executed, the sources are already waiting for you in path `/project`.

Comment: That's what i thought it should have worked but when i do git fetch i get the error: Permission denied (publickey)

Comment: Sure you get the error. You simply should NOT git fetch. Everything is already there. Just work with the code.

Answer (score 0):

BitBucket Pipelines automatically checks out the repository upon running. However, if you want to make changes to the repository (e.g. `git tag` or `git push`) you will need to add the SSH keys according to the post you have already found (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-ssh-keys-in-bitbucket-pipelines-847452940.html). That works for our environment.

Can you post the full `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file?